# Function Return Issue?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

In my VB.Net program I have found two (2) warnings shows the following messages:

**Function doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used**

help me where is the problem and to fix it. The following snapshot is where the warning error indicates:

The Firs Warning near 'End Function'

```
'Executes SQL commands to the system database
Public Function ExecSQL(ByVal sql As String)
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand(sql)
        Try
            RefreshConnection()
            com.Connection = con
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
End Function
```

The Second Waring near 'End Function'

```
'Get the value of an specific field in a given sql string
    Public Function GetField(ByVal sql As String, ByVal field As String)
        Try
            RefreshConnection()
            Dim com As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            Dim dReader As MySqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader

            While dReader.Read
                GetField = dReader(field).ToString
            End While
            dReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: This code is flawed in an important way not related to your question: it forces you to build sql queries in a way that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. **It's practically begging to get hacked.**

Comment: Also: single shared connection is not optimal in .Net. Instead, .Net relies on a feature called connection pooling such that in most cases you should use a new connection object for each call to the database. Really. Instead, just keep a single shared connection _string_ handy for creating your connection.

Comment: Oh, and turn on Option Strict!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because in the exception handler you actually return the exception object `ex`. You're not returning anything if no exception occurs. You could explicitly add `Return Nothing` just above `Catch ex as Exception`, but I guess from the message that VB is doing that automatically for you...

By the way: What's the point returning the exception to the caller? Put the message box into the calling method and wrap your call in `Try-Catch` there. A method that's obviously not meant to interact with the user shouldn't show messages at all. And then you can just pass the exception up until you end up the presentation layer.

Long story short: No message boxes in business logic. User information only in presentation layer.

---

After reading your second method: Things are even worse here! If the data reader has rows, you set the result of the method to the last (!) result you found (this is a WTF in itself, but another story). If an error occurs, the result is an object of type `Exception`, so the calling code even needs to make sure to decide whether the result of the function call is actually a field value or an exception!

This is really bad design my friend.

---

You asked for fixed code:

```
'Executes SQL commands to the system database
Public Sub ExecSQL(ByVal sql As String)
    Dim com As New MySqlCommand(sql)

    RefreshConnection()
    com.Connection = con
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

'Get the value of an specific field in a given sql string
Public Function GetField(ByVal sql As String, ByVal field As String)
    RefreshConnection()
    Dim com As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    Dim dReader As MySqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader

    GetField = Nothing

    While dReader.Read
        GetField = dReader(field).ToString
    End While
    dReader.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: No, because that would render my answer invalid. I can give you an example in my answer.

Comment: So I've fixed your code. Please note that now the caller has to handle the exceptions. And you should *really* spend a minute of thought on whether it is correct to have that `While dReader.Read`. What happens if more than one row is read from the database?

Comment: Yes you are correct. your correction is works. but the second function GetField steel has the Warning error.

Comment: I slightly edited the second one so that `Nothing` is returned in case the reader doesn't have rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws here. In the interest of brevity, I'll just post some improved code:

```
'Executes SQL commands to the system database
Private Function ExecSQL(ByVal sql As String, ByVal params As IEnumerable(Of MySqlParameter))
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString()), _
          com As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

        For Each param As MySqlParameter in params
           com.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next param
        cn.Open()
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Function

'Get the value of an specific field in a given sql string
Private Function GetField(Of T)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal params As IEnumerable(Of MySqlParameter), ByVal field As String) As T
     Using cn As New MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
           com As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

         For Each param As MySqlParameter In params
            com.Parameters.Add(param)
         Next param
         cn.Open()

         Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
             While rdr.Read()
                 Return CType(rdr(field), T)
             End While
         End Using
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```